# Optimize the shell script code with iterative commands within if..else conditions

Tags: python, bash, shell

Run my project pipeline with the **run.sh** file and it will yield successful output.
But if it doesn't work, I should restart the pipeline with the same command.

Instead, I give the argument to pass in the run.sh file where it does not start from the failed step.

```
echo "Usage : file.sh step"

if [ "$step" = "" ]; then
     python -u -m utils.py
     python -u -m apple.py
     python -u -m banana.py
     python -u -m cat.py
     python -u -m dog.py
elif [ "$step" = "apple" ]; then
     python -u -m apple.py
     python -u -m banana.py
     python -u -m cat.py
     python -u -m dog.py
elif [ "$step" = "banana" ]; then
     python -u -m banana.py
     python -u -m cat.py
     python -u -m dog.py
elif [ "$step" = "cat" ]; then
     python -u -m cat.py
     python -u -m dog.py
elif [ "$step" = "dog" ]; then
     python -u -m dog.py
else 
    echo "Issue"
fi
```

Command to execute the above code: run.sh step

**Ex: run.sh "banana"**

Answer (score 5):

In general, when matching a single string (like `"$step"`) against a series of other strings/patterns, you should use [`case`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) instead of a series of `if`...`elif`... statements. It's especially useful here, because in bash v4.0 and later you can use `;&` between clauses to mean "execute the next clause as well (whether or not its pattern matches)". Something like this:

```
case "$step" in
    "")     python -u -m utils.py ;&
    apple)  python -u -m apple.py ;&
    banana) python -u -m banana.py ;&
    cat)    python -u -m cat.py ;&
    dog)    python -u -m dog.py ;;
    *)      echo "Issue" ;;
esac
```

So that e.g. if `"$step"` is "apple", it'll execute the `apple` case, then execution will flow on through the `banana`, `cat`, and `dog` cases. The `;;` between the `dog` and `*` cases means it *doesn't* flow into the final case, and that final `*` will match anything (that wasn't matched by an earlier case), so it effectively functions like an `else` clause.